# Eclipse: Release build confusion: How to identify?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I've been updating Eclipse automatically between Indigo RC releases.

I currently have:
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110609-2236

In the eclipse site, i cannot identify which is the current Indigo release, except here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/
Build id: 20110613-1736 (latter build, 1736??)

How can i know that my release is updated to the Final Indigo Release?
How can i see the release listed in the download pages? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [release repository](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) only has the official 3.7, 3.7.1 and 3.7.x.